# Any variation of SCVMM or prev gen VMM product that can run as guest on a Hyper V VM under Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, scvmm

I just downloaded and tried the SCVMM 2012 Evaluation VHDs and realized that the Document mentioned 2008 R2 as a VM Host (probably as a minimum).

Is there a variation/ previous generation product in the same line (SC VMM/ VMM) from Microsoft that can be run under Hyper V on Windows Server 2008?

Is there or was there a similar Evaluation VHDs or Setups available to try out?

PS: I know this is older versions and everyone recommends going to 2012 and 2016, but I need to "prepare" and work on some older stuff before we can migrate them to 2012 R2.

Thoughts?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking if there's a version of SCVMM that can manage Hyper-V under Windows Server 2008 or are you asking if there's a version of SCVMM that will run as a guest VM under Hyper-V in Windows Server 2008?

Comment: @joeqwerty - The Latter, Guest.

Comment: OK. This should help - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794868(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There were some issues earlier, but now SCVMM 2012 Eval VHD is running in Hyper V on Win Server 2008.

For some weird reason Hyper V installed and was ready to use so I figured it was something else.

But on a dual/ side boot from a 2012 R2 instance (since we assumed 2008 was causing some issue with the Eval VHD), when trying to add the Hyper V role, realized that VT was not enabled on the BIOS.

So, enabled VT in the BIOS, installed Hyper V on 2012 R2, got the Eval VHD working.

Went back to Server 2008 and this time Hyper V worked.

It's interesting to note the difference in behavior between Server 2008 and 2012 R2 when it came to adding Hyper V role and then later executing a VM.

PS: Also, read somewhere that Integration Services pack causes some issue when installed from a 2012 R2 Host on to a 2008 Guest. So, that's something I have yet to verify.